# How are AEAD, GCM, CBC, Poly1305, EtM, MtE and E&M related?

Tags: hash, authentication, mac, openssl, integrity

I am using OpenSSL 1.1.1 to implement a TLS 1.3 communication module so I tried to learn how data integrity and authentication is ensured. I read a lot about AEAD, GCM, CBC, Poly1305, EtM, MtE and E&M to the point that I know what they are, but I do not know how they are related to each other. My Questions are

1. I know that TLS 1.3 uses AEAD. Does that mean that it is EtM, MtE or E&M?
2. Is GCM an EtM algorithm for block ciphers?
3. What does OpenSSL use by default? EtM, MtE or E&M? Which are supported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I do not know how they are related to each other.

- EtM, MtE and E&M are generic constructions that take pairs of schemes that satisfy weaker security notions (chosen-plaintext security and unforgeability) and turn them into AEAD-secure schemes.
- GCM is a construction that takes a 128-bit block cipher and turns it into - an AEAD-secure scheme and internally uses something like EtM for that.
- CBC is one construction that takes a block cipher and turns it into something that is suitable for the encryption part of the EtM, MtE and E&M schemes (though it is admittedly not easy to do this right in face of padding / timing attacks).
- Poly1305 is a one-time MAC (that is a MAC that is only secure when used at most once for a given key) which can be paired up with e.g. a block cipher (to generate one-time keys from nonces) to become a regular MAC suitable for the MAC part in EtM, MtE and E&M schemes.

> What does OpenSSL use by default?

[Apparently](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/05/04/tlsv1.3/) OpenSSL will default to using either AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305 for symmetric encryption

> Which are supported?

TLS 1.3 abandoned the concept of these generic compositions so you will only find complete AEAD schemes to be specified as ciphersuite.

Comment: It appears that the OpenSSL wiki is down (due to some configuration error), so I couldn't look into the TLS 1.3 page there to see the current supported list.

Comment: 'use' is ambiguous. Yes, OpenSSL 1.1.1 by default _offers_ or _accepts_ AES-128/256-GCM and ChaCha-Poly, but what is _negotiated_ on a particular connection also depends on the peer, and whether the server uses client or server preference.